# Is there a way to trigger point hit on an xAxis hover

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I am trying to get the datapoint hover to trigger when the user hovers over any part of the chart based on the xAxis.

I don't want them to have to hover directly over the datapoint.

I tried setting pointHitRadius, but of course that is a radius so the hitbox for the dataPoints start overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `intersect` as `false` under your chart's options `hover` configuration which by default is set to `true`.

```js
var options = {
  hover: {
    intersect: false
  }
};
```

From the [official docs:](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/)

> If `true`, the hover mode only applies when the mouse position intersects an item on the chart.

Setting it to `false` means the hover will trigger when the user hovers on any part of the chart based on the xAxis.

Comment: Fantastic!  Beautiful, concise answer, I was looking at all the wrong settings.  Appreciate the help!